# python ftplib.error_perm: 530 Permission denied

Tags: python, sockets, ftp, permission-denied

I've tried the script below:

==========================================

```
import ftplib,socket,sys,time,re
ftp = ftplib.FTP()
ftp.connect('10.108.244.15',21,10)
ftp.login('root','abc123')
```

===========================================

when I try to login as root

a error occured!

## it says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 384, in login
resp = self.sendcmd('USER ' + user)
File "C:\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 244, in sendcmd
return self.getresp()
File "C:\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 219, in getresp
raise error_perm, resp
ftplib.error_perm: 530 Permission denied.
```

=====================================

but when I try to login as normal user of the ftp server , nothing occured !

Also ,when I login as root by other tools such as XManager /SSH  Client,  it worked well

I wonder why

thanks for your answer

Comment: Usually you can not login as root via FTP, the other tools use SSH as the connection. Overall this is not a Python but a server configuration question.